# pgfplots need help with complicated stacked bar chart using selected rows from data table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I'm trying to recreate this bar chart from the data table found in the MWE below.

[image: example chart]

It involves doing a couple things that I can't figure out:

1. stack positive and negative bars on the same axis, such that the negative numbers don't merely subtract from the positive ones (this is the default behavior of `xbar stacked`)
2. selecting only certain rows from the table. For the blue bars I need only rows 1-3 (counting the column headers as row 0). For the red bars I need two instances of row 4 and one of row 5.
3. creating the lines that show the values from the SUM columns and creating data labels.
4. creating a legend using the column headers of columns 2 and 3 (even though column 3 contains no real data).
5. reverse the ordering of the items on the y axis. Notice that the categories in the MWE count down from top to bottom; I'd like the opposite.

You'll see where I've got so far by looking at the MWE. As for the rest, I'm rather baffled. I need to automate this process and this is the format the data comes in (so reformatting the underlying data table is a suboptimal solution).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
category,value,negvalue
cat1,3,0
cat2,5,0
cat3,1,0
cat1and2n,-6,0
cat3n,-3,0
cat1sum,-3,0
cat2sum,-1,0
cat3sum,-2,0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
yticklabels from table={\datatable}{category},
ytick=data]

\addplot table[
y expr=\coordindex,
x=value]
{data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you don't want to reformat the data table 'outside' your typesetting process, you can do it 'inside' with tools like `pgfplotstable`, `datatool` or `lua`. Look, for example, at: [pgfplotstable or datatool?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44105/1952), [Insert libreoffice table as input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60378/1952), [Rearrange data in pgfplotstable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21523/1952)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the ability to manipulate tables within tex. However, it seems like there should be a way to accomplish this plot without reformatting. It's not *that* complicated....

Answer (score 4):

For 2.: you can filter the rows like in [Calculate and draw difference of two plots automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62476/calculate-and-draw-difference-of-two-plots-automatically)

```
\pgfkeys{
    /tr/rowfilter/.style 2 args={
        /pgfplots/x filter/.append code={
            \edef\arga{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\argb{#2}
            \ifx\arga\argb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

but this filter is only applicable for fixed contens

```
\addplot table[/tr/rowfilter={category}{cat1sum}] {data.dat};
```

but this gives you only the 6th row. Unfortunately I don't know TeX enough to check for a pattern like 'cart[0-9]sum'